# What defines the oxidizing/reducing power of a coordination compound?

Tags: redox, coordination-compounds, oxidation-state

For example, I came across a problem in which I was asked to determine whether the complex $\ce{[Cr(H2O)6]Cl2}$ is an oxidizing or reducing agent.

How should I proceed? My teacher told me its the EAN number that defines this. What are your views?

Comment: I was looking at some revision lately on this. My textbook/other refs indicated a bit about `standard electrode potentials` as a reference in determining a species as an oxidant or reductant. Given that there's `Cl` and a metal `Cr`, I would presume this is a reductant (note: reducing power decreases in this order: `Na > Zn > Pb > H2 > Cu > Ag > Br- > Mn2+ > F-)` and S-block metals are good reductants. Why not take a look at reactions (both acidic and basic) which involves this agent?

Comment: Yep your approach is also right. I was thinking that since the Cr here is in +2 oxidation state it has an electronic configuration - [Ar] 3d^4 so it can do two things -

Comment: 1. It could gain an electron to achieve a stable [Ar] 3d^5 configuration or

Comment: 2. It could lose an electron to have half filled t2g subshell as per crystal field theory

Comment: I just did a quick search online : coordination compounds redox, it looks like coordinated compounds' redox are of a different level altogether. I may not have sufficient knowledge to address that aspect at all. Keen to know an answer you get.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is EAN? I cannot imagine how [this EAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number) has anything to do with redox processes. Is it [effective atomic number $Z_\text{eff}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_atomic_number)? But then there is "number number", so I'm lost.

Comment: See the logic with EAN here is the transition metal atoms tend to have the exact number of electrons as present in the noble gases of their respective periods. For example a 3d series atom  would like to have an EAN number of 36 since that is the number of electrons present in Krypton. In order to do so it could gain or lose electrons to make its Effective Atomic No. 36.